# How to place multiple columns as a single column most easily in R dataframe?

Tags: r

How to make values in columns 1,2,3,4 appear as values in a single column 1 in which values are placed one below the other? The contents are non numeric. I am unable to install tidy verse package for some reason. Any other way possible to accomplish?  My dataframe df looks something like this

`df`
 
`Person1 Person2 Person3
 Doctor  Self    No
 Friend  No      Others`
`Self    Others  Doctor`
 I want the dataframe to be:
`df1`
`Person`
`Doctor`
`Friend`
`Self`
`Self`
`No`
`Others`
`No`
`Others`
`Doc`

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example to illustrate what you want to do. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how to make a minimal reproducible example.

Without that I can only guess what you mean and suggest to have a look at 

    ?reshape

Comment: Check out base R reshape functionality `help(reshape)`. You are trying to reshape from wide to long.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
data.table::melt()
```

or

```
reshape::melt()
```

Example

```
library(reshape)
mdata <- melt(mydata, id=c("id","te"))
```

Result

```
d   t   v   value
1   1   x1  5
1   2   x1  3
2   1   x1  6
2   2   x1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) excellent answer on how to make a reproducible example in R. It'll help others to provide answers faster.

You can find a way to get your data in a long format using `tidyr` (assuming your columns are filled with stirngs as you mentioned).

```r
> df <- data.frame(col1 = c("some", "strings"), col2 = c("more", "strings"), col3 = c("lotof", "strings"))
> df
     col1    col2    col3
1    some    more   lotof
2 strings strings strings

> library(tidyr)
> pivot_longer(df, c(col1, col2, col3))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  name  value  
  <chr> <fct>  
1 col1  some   
2 col2  more   
3 col3  lotof  
4 col1  strings
5 col2  strings
6 col3  strings
```

Regarding package installation problems, could you copy the error that pops out and the console output of `sessionInfo()`